# Wait for Twilio call to finish and get call status in C#

Tags: c#, twilio

I m trying to develop an application with Twilio voice call SDK to make a phone call.
The problem is that when it calls following code

```
var call = CallResource.CreateAsync(
                url: new Uri("http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml"),
                to: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber("XXXX"),
                from: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber("XXXX")
            );
```

then I need to wait till the call is completed and then get the final call status.

Currently, it is triggering the call and executing the next line of code.

Thanks in advance

I tried to use wait() function but it hang up there ony

Comment: Have you tried `await CallResource.CreateAsync()` ? I assume `CallResource.CreateAsync()` returns `Task<SomeClass>`, but without awaiting it you get the task itself not the result.
Also, without knowing this API, It seems like you only *create* your resource, but you do not execute ithe call

Comment: await CallResource.CreateAsync() would be the correct way to call this method. It would probably execute the other way but likely cancelled by a thread clean-up. This method both creates and executes the call - the phone will ring. But, the method will not return the events that the original poster is seeking. Webhooks are needed using the StatusCallback parameter to set the URL where the webhooks should be sent.

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to do this on a server, desktop, or Blazor application (which is what your code suggests), you will need to setup a [webhook](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/webhooks/webhooks-overview) controller to receive the Twilio status event webhooks. These webhooks will notify your application that a call state as changed. The next challenge, is your controller will then have to notify other parts of your application that an event was received. I am using SignalR for this capability.

A second option is to use the [Twilio Voice Javascript SDK](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/sdks/javascript).

Here is an example:

```
call.on('disconnect', call => {
 console.log('The call has been disconnected.');
});
```

There is a [Disconnect](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/sdks/javascript/twiliocall#events) event that will fire when the call disconnects. This is a good option for web applications that are already using Javascript.

For my project I am using Blazor so I use the Controller (Azure Function) and SignalR to bring real-time notifications into web apps. The controller receives the webhook and sends a message to the user interface using SignalR.

A third, and not good, option is to repeatedly poll the Twilio Voicecall end-point to get the current status of the call. This does not scale well and will cause you many problems down the road (and is not super accurate for time sensititve applications). I list it as an option so people know what not to do.